# Lua Sockets Module cpath

Tags: lua

I'm trying to use the sockets module in a script and I keep encountering a issue where the script is unable to find socket.core.  Is there anyway for me to point to exactly where the core.dll is?  I've tried using cpath and I can never seem to get it to work. I just want to be able to say "C:/folder/folder/folder/core.dll"

```
package.cpath = 'F:/Folder/Foldertwo/Game/agame/Beta/Scripts/libs/socket/?.dll;' .. package.cpath
```

Comment: Try `'F:/Folder/Foldertwo/Game/agame/Beta/Scripts/libs/?.dll;'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@EgorSkriptunoff is correct in his comment: `socket.lua` (which is a lua module) loads `socket.core` (which is a dynamic library), so you won't be able to load it from `folder/core.dll` as the default searcher will be looking for `socket/core.dll`.

If you really want to load it from `folder/core.dll`, you may try to load it yourself and assign the returned value to `package.preload['socket.core']`. This way when `socket.lua` loads the module, it will get the value to return from `package.preload` key without loading the module.

Comment: I managed to get it working by setting the LUA_PATH and LUA_CPATH manually in my environment variables on windows.  But now I see to be having the issue of "dynamic libraries not enabled; check your Lua installation"

Comment: @Lxuz, your lua executable needs to be compiled with `LUA_USE_DLOPEN` (or one of the options that enables it).

Comment: Sadly it turns out that the environment that I'm trying to run my LUA in doesn't allow for dll loading.  I'm wanting to use a remote debugger but from what I can tell they all require the luasockets.  Not sure if there is anyway to bypass this dll restriction most of my ideas seem to complex for me to implement.

Comment: What environment is that? If you use a debugger like Mobdebug, you can try to mimic luasocket API, but you'd still need to have a way to send data back and forth between the debugger and the controller/IDE.

Comment: Cryengine, for whatever reason they don't allow you use dll loading.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CryEngine, but I see it provides CryNetwork that supports TCP sockets, which leaves some hope that it's possible to use it to implement a layer that mimics luasocket API. You'd need socket.tcp/settimeout/connect and client:send/receive methods.